# How do I hide an element when "-" is present?

Tags: jquery

I worked out this jQuery code to hide a shopping cart link when it is empty. It works great, but the shopping cart reappears occasionally with a"-" where there once was a "0". Aside from hiding the shopping cart when its value is "0", how can I hide it also if its value is a hyphen, "-"?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   var x = $("span#wsite-nav-cart").text();

   if (x == 0){
     $("#wsite-nav-cart-a").hide();
    } else {
     $("#wsite-nav-cart-a").show();
   };    

});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   var x = $("span#wsite-nav-cart").text();

   if (x == 0){
     $("#wsite-nav-cart-a").hide();
    } else if(x == "-")  {
     $("#wsite-nav-cart-a").hide();
    } else {
     $("#wsite-nav-cart-a").show();
   };    

});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sure this code is correct, but I can't really test it because sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Does this sound like a jQuery code conflict?

Comment: are there any erros in the console? is the shopping cart loaded via ajax? is it possible to make a fiddle and show it to us?